# Read-only attributes via properties versus via documentation

Tags: python, properties, attributes, private, readonly

In Python I'm writing a class where some attributes must remain constant during the object lifetime.

One way is to use properties:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        '''Create a Foo object

        x -- list of int (READ-ONLY)
        y -- float
        '''
        # Save x and y and ensure they are int
        self._x = [int(xx) for xx in x]
        self.y = float(y)

    @property
    def x(self):
        # Return a copy of self._x to prevent accidental modification
        return self._x.copy()
```

Is it considerered to be a good practice? Should I only rely on the documentation to exhibit which attributes are writable, and which are not? Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that there's almost no technical way to prevent someone to access your object's implementation and modify it if he really wants to.

Now wrt/ your question / example:

- using an implementation attribute (`_x`) and readonly property makes the intent quite clear
- if your list is really supposed to be immutable, use a `tuple()` instead. It's semantically debatable (`tuple` is for position-based records - think relational db records etc - not an immutable list), but make sure it will be immutable and avoids having to make copies.
- you still *do* want to clearly document this attribute should "remain constant" for the instance's lifetime.

Comment: If someone really wants to modify private attributes, that is not my business anymore. I'm more concerned by accidental modifications. A tuple seems indeed more appropriate than a list. There is unfortunately not always immutable equivalents of mutable types: for example dictionnary, numpy.ndarray, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your code slightly to get at least a complaint

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        '''Create a Foo object

        x -- list of int (READ-ONLY)
        y -- float
        '''
        # Save x and y and ensure they are int
        self._x = [int(xx) for xx in x]
        self.y = float(y)

    @property
    def x(self): return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self,value):
        raise AttributeError('Don\'t touch my private parts, please')
```

And then if you try to change things:

```
>>>> a = Foo([1,2,3,4,5],0.2)

>>>> a.x
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

>>>> a.x = 3
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-87-0a024de0ab56>", line 1, in <module>
    a.x = 3

  File "D:/pydump/gcd_lcm_tests.py", line 230, in x
    raise AttributeError('Don\'t touch my private parts, please')

AttributeError: Don't touch my private parts, please
```

Instead of raising an exception you can quietly `pass` but it is better to complain in my opinion.

Comment: My code already raises an AttributeError exception when trying to modify the attribute `Foo.x`, this is the default behavior when there is a property without a setter. Thus I don't find useful to add a setter.

Comment: @NicolasBedou True but does it also mention why it raises? That's pretty important. Also I think your question is not about protection but rather if somebody uses an instance property inside a function or somewhere else whether it gets overwritten accidentally, not necessarily restricting property access.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are after is called:

- [Immutable Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object#Python)

**Example #1:**

```
from collections import namedtuple

foo = namedtuple("Immutable", ["a", "b"])
```

**Example #2:**

```
class Foo(object):
    __slots__ = ()
```

In both cases it's an error to set attributes or mutable the objects in any way.

**Demo(s):**

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> class Foo(object):
...     __slots__ = ()
... 
>>> Bar = namedtuple("Bar", ["a", "b"])
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> bar = Bar(1, 2)
>>> foo.a = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'a'
>>> foo.a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'a'
>>> bar.a
1
>>> bar.a = 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Note that with a `namedtuple` object you cannot change any of it's attributes once they are created. This is quite handy.

Comment: namedtuples and __slots__ are convenient, but what if a class contains both writable and readonly attributes? And is it a recommended practice to return copies of mutable attributes to prevent any modification?

Comment: I think this all depends on your *exact* requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an attribute to be non-modifiable, *don't* return a copy on dereferencing: You'll just confuse things further and lead to weird bugs. If you want to enforce non-modifiability, make it into a property and make *the setter* refuse to modify it.

How well that works depends on the details of your data structure. If your attribute is a list, for example, you can intercept modification of the list itself, but if it has mutable elements you would still be able to modify *their* attributes.